# Strange behavior of CTE

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I just answered this: [Generate scripts with new ids (also for dependencies)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31382745/5089204)

My first attempt was this:

```
DECLARE @Form1 UNIQUEIDENTIFIER=NEWID();
DECLARE @Form2 UNIQUEIDENTIFIER=NEWID();

DECLARE @tblForms TABLE(id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,FormName VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tblForms VALUES(@Form1,'test1'),(@Form2,'test2');

DECLARE @tblFields TABLE(id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,FormId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,FieldName VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tblFields VALUES(NEWID(),@Form1,'test1.1'),(NEWID(),@Form1,'test1.2'),(NEWID(),@Form1,'test1.3')
                            ,(NEWID(),@Form2,'test2.1'),(NEWID(),@Form2,'test2.2'),(NEWID(),@Form2,'test2.3');

--These are the originalIDs
SELECT frms.id,frms.FormName
      ,flds.id,flds.FieldName
FROM @tblForms AS frms
INNER JOIN @tblFields AS flds ON frms.id=flds.FormId ;                           

--The same with new ids
WITH FormsWithNewID AS
(
    SELECT NEWID() AS myNewFormID
          ,*
    FROM @tblForms            
)
SELECT frms.myNewFormID, frms.id,frms.FormName
      ,NEWID() AS myNewFieldID,flds.FieldName
FROM FormsWithNewID AS frms
INNER JOIN @tblFields AS flds ON frms.id=flds.FormId
```

The second select should deliver - at least I thought so - two values in "myNewFormID", each three times... But it comes up with 6 different values. This would mean, that the CTE's "NEWID()" is done for each row of the final result set. What am I missing?

Comment: uncertain about marking it as a duplicate, but the answer on the post might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17110816/using-newid-with-cte-to-produce-random-subset-of-rows-produces-odd-results

Comment: Looked that up. It is related but quite something else for me. There's the point, that a CTE delivers different counts of rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding of CTEs is wrong. They are not simply a table variable that's filled with the results of the query - instead, they are a query on their own. Note that CTEs can be used recursively - this would be quite a sight with table variables :)

From MSDN:

> A common table expression (CTE) can be thought of as a temporary result set that is defined within the execution scope of a single SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or CREATE VIEW statement. A CTE is similar to a derived table in that it is not stored as an object and lasts only for the duration of the query. Unlike a derived table, a CTE can be self-referencing and can be referenced multiple times in the same query.

The "can be thought" of is a bit deceiving - sure, it can be thought of, but it's *not* a result set. You don't see this manifesting when you're only using pure functions, but as you've noticed, `newId` is *not* pure. In reality, it's more like a named subquery - in your example, you'll get the same thing if you just move the query from the CTE to the `from` clause directly.

To illustrate this even further, you can add another join on the CTE to the query:

```
WITH FormsWithNewID AS
(
    SELECT NEWID() AS myNewFormID
          ,*
    FROM @tblForms            
)
SELECT frms.myNewFormID, frms.id,frms.FormName
      ,NEWID() AS myNewFieldID,flds.FieldName,
      frms2.myNewFormID
FROM FormsWithNewID AS frms
INNER JOIN @tblFields AS flds ON frms.id=flds.FormId  
left join FormsWithNewID as frms2 on frms.id = frms2.id
```

You'll see that the `frms2.myNewFormID` contains *different myNewFormIDs*.

Keep this in mind - you can only treat the CTE as a result set when you're only using pure functions on non-changing data; in other words, if executing the same query in a serializable transaction isolation level twice will produce the same result sets.

Comment: Would you have expected this? Would you have expected, that the "rows" of a CTE could be changed / recalculated / whatever later in your query? I'm quite surprised...

Comment: @Shnugo Oh, I wasn't trying to insult you or anything. Most people indeed seem to think that's how CTEs work - and they're teaching them that way to others. The realization only came to me when I was playing around with them - indeed, my colleagues were very much set on the "CTE == table variable" idea, so I had to show them concrete examples like this. Despite the fact that they used recursive CTEs in the past. Neither of the two ways is inherently more suprising - it's just that you're far more likely to be taught that CTEs are like table variables, so when you find out they aren't...

Comment: sorry if I sounded rough... There was absolutely no offendence or insult! I gave the you first up vote :-) This is just an expression of my astonishment... Thank you for your valueable input!

Comment: @Luaan My favorite part of this site is when I go looking for questions to answer and instead learn something myself.  Excellent answer.

Answer (score 0):

NEWID() returns a value every time it is executed. Whenever you use it you get a new value 
For example,

```
select top 5 newid()
from sys.tables
order by newid()
```

You will not see them order by because the selected field is produced with different values than the Order By field

Comment: This is clear... The question is the CTE. For my understanding a CTE is quite similar to a table valued variable. You fill it above your SELECT and then you use it later. Its content should by fixed. But in this case the two rows of @tblForms get a NEWID within the CTE, but still come up with **again** new ids in the SELECT...

Comment: "SELECT NEWID() AS myNewFormID, * FROM @tblForms" you are using here NewID() function producing new identifiers. This is a new field with new values.

Comment: Yes, but @tblForms contains exactly two rows. So the CTE - at least I thought so - should contain exactly two rows (with new IDs) too. The later join should express this. But - obviously - the NEWID() is done in a later step producing 6 different IDs instead of two sets of three...